# AttributeError tf-nightly class weight

Tags: tensorflow

I am working with tf-nightly version.

In the previous version, class weights as the array input works.

But, the nightly version is throwing the error.

```
weights = np.array([3.4,  10.11,  10.67,  11.52,  0.23,  0.001,  19.86])

model.fit(data, labels, epochs=10,class_weight = weights)
```

Error Message:

```
class_ids = list(sorted(class_weight.keys()))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

weights in the dictionary form,

```
weights = {0: 3.4,  1: 10.11,  2: 10.67,  3: 11.52,  4: 0.23,  5: 0.001,  6: 19.86}
```

Comment: `ValueError: class_weight not supported for 3+ dimensional targets` I don't think this means more than three classes are not supported; rather it means the shape of targets/output values of the model should not have 3+ dimensions. What is the output shape of your model or the targets?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a change in the `class_weight` parameter it has always been a dictionary object.

```
class_weight    Optional dictionary mapping class indices (integers)
```

This is [definition](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) is from the stable version and not from the nightly. I went back to check the API documentation from [tensorflow2.0rc](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) and even in that documentation, it is a dictionary and not an array.

So to answer short, it is not a change in Nightly, but it since `rc2.0` in TensorFlow.

In which version were you able to use your above code without issues? and
Did you want to try `sample_weight` instead? `sample_weight` does take an array of weights.

I hope my answer helps you.

Comment: class weight in the form of array worked in case of tf 2.2.  However, in both versions (tf 2.2 or tf-nightly), following error occurred when changed into dictionary format. `ValueError: `class_weight` not supported for 3+ dimensional targets.`

Comment: @thunder could you show an example of your dictionary object? It will help me understand how you are using it. Also a bit of a dummy code to run and debug?

Comment: weights in the dictionary form is updated in thequestion. i'll put a dummy code later

Comment: Thank you. As per this issue it looks like I will also need to look at the model. You can check this issue out. https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3653